# idTabs jQuery plugin not working

Tags: jquery

I have a simple html page that I am working on to test the functionality of idTabs (http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/).  I cannot get it working properly.  The jquery sources appear to be loading properly (checked via Chrome Console).  The files are in a folder on my desktop.. Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="idTabs"> 
<li><a href="#jquery">jQuery</a></li> 
<li><a href="#official">Tabs 3</a></li> 
</ul> 
<div id="jquery">If you haven't checked out ...</div> 
<div id="official">idTabs is only a simple ...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here is my output]

[image: Here is my file structure]

Comment: You should invoke $( "#idTabs" ).tabs(); on document.ready().Please refer to https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: This doesn't work either  >>  

$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#idTabs" ).tabs();
});

Comment: You're missing some CSS + Waqar ment idTabs() -- http://jsfiddle.net/y44fpybz/ 
PS.: I've added the CSS in the 'external resources'

Comment: Thx for the fiddle @alitrix!  Looks like I didn't include the css

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="idTtabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#jquery">jQuery</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#official">Tabs 3</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <div id="jquery">
    If you haven't checked out ...
  </div>
  <div id="official">
    idTabs is only a simple ...
  </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#idTabs" ).tabs(); 
})
</script>
```

You did not ready the example carefully provided in the link i had send you.